# Problema leyendo archivos txt en binario

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy intentando hacer un programa que lea un archivo txt en binario y lo muestre en consola ya traducido.
Usuario: rabisa
Contraseña: 12345
El problema es el siguiente, y es que en principio "lo traduce bien" pero de una forma muy extraña:

[image: Consola]

Este es el código que he utilizado:

Main:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        try {

            FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(new File("login.txt"));
            
            int ch;     
            /*
             * Creamos un bucle para leer la información
             * mientras haya bytes en el archivo.
             */
            while ((ch = fileIS.read()) != -1) {
                
                System.out.println((char) ch);      //Imprimimos el objeto leido en consola
            }
            fileIS.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

DatosUsuario:

```
public class DatosUsuario {

    
    private String usuario;
    private String contrasenna;
    
    
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public String getContrasenna() {
        return contrasenna;
    }
    public void setContrasenna(String contrasenna) {
        this.contrasenna = contrasenna;
    }

}
```

Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Para leer los caracteres del archivo puedes usar las clases `InputStream` e `InputStreamReader` pero especificando una codificación como "ISO_8859_1" para evitar el problema que comentas:

```
   try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("login.txt"));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        int r;
        while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) r;
            System.out.println(ch);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred. " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred. " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Si no defines la codificación usando `Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);`  obtienes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al definir la codificación `Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);` podrás obtener correctamente la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]